# Let $O_1$, $O_2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be two open sets and $\phi:O_1\rightarrow O_2$ a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

**QUESTION:** Let $O_1$, $O_2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be two open sets and $\phi:O_1\rightarrow O_2$ a diffeomorphism. If $S_1\subset O_1$ is a surface, then $S_2=\phi(S_1)$ is also a surface.

**MY ATTEMPT:** Due to $S_1$ be a surface then exists a parametrization $X: U\rightarrow S_1$ of $S_1$. Now, the hint is to show that $\phi\circ X: U\rightarrow S_2$ is a parametrization of $S_2$. But here is where I'm struggling. Would someone help me?

Comment: What’s the definition of a parameterization?

Comment: I guess I've just found my mistake. In this case, $X\circ \phi:O_1\rightarrow S_1$ is called reparametrization of $X$, right? However I don't know how to write and prove that $\phi^{-1}\circ X: U \rightarrow S_2$ is a parametrization...

Comment: I wrote wrong, the correct question is: $\phi\circ X:U \rightarrow S_2$ instead of $\phi^{-1}\circ X:U \rightarrow S_2$